# JavaFX zoom issue using setOnZoom

Tags: java, events, javafx, zooming, scrollpane

I have a ScrollPane that contains a StackPane, and I added an event handler to the StackPane like so:

```
private void setupZoom() {
    scaleX = pane.getScaleX(); // I only store this to be able to revert the changes
    scaleY = pane.getScaleY();

    pane.setOnZoom(new EventHandler<ZoomEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ZoomEvent event) {
            pane.setScaleX(pane.getScaleX()*event.getZoomFactor());
            pane.setScaleY(pane.getScaleY()*event.getZoomFactor());
            //System.out.println(event.getZoomFactor());
            event.consume();
        }
    });
}
```

where pane is the StackPane. If the zoom gesture is detected, this works perfectly well. But it simply is not detected most of the time. If I start the application and try it, I notice that it either works fine or not at all. Out of several trials, 50% or so work. I investigated which element has the focus, but that does not seem to matter (the scrollPane has it all the time, both in working and not working trials.) 
Any ideas what I do wrong?